# How to activate control programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, controls

I have simple view with 2 text fields and OK/Cancel buttons. When view loads can I make the first text field already active to begin input immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` call:

```
[myFirstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```